# preg_match_all for <option></option> to get all matching values

Tags: php, html, preg-match-all

Here is the string.

```
$string = <option class="abcd" value="1.5">Some Text with White Spaces</option>
```

I want to get all matching variables (`1.5` & `Some Text with White Spaces`) using preg_match_all or something similar. I was doing this a long ago but I don't remember it now. Hope you can help...

Comment: Have you considered using a DOM parser?

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: @Pekka I'm not so familiar with that. Anyway, I think I got a solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't answer a html & regex question on Stack Overflow without mentioning *please use a [parser](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)*.

However, if you were really keen on a regex, you could see below.

---

If your strings look like that, then you could use...

```
preg_match_all('/<option\sclass="[^"]*"\svalue="([^"]*)">([^>]*)<\/option>/', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

`$matches[1]` will have the `value` attribute and `$matches[2]` will have the text node.